# Testing Android application with different-sized screens

Tags: android, screen

I have a question for you guys about multiple screens.

I am testing an Android application for different-sized screens using emulator. The application have been initially developed for resolution 320*480. I know it is not good and I have problems in my code. Moreover, I have used pixels in some places of code instead of dip. You see, I am not a professional in Android. In any case, there is no problem for devices with resolution 320*480 and 480*800. For the second one the application looks stretched. According to documentation it should be so. But, when I am trying resolutions 540*960 or 1024*600 the application occupies just a part of screen and it seems to be 320*480. The question is: why it didn't stretched the application to the whole screen? How can I do it?

I have read Supporting Multiple Screens guide here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels, but I haven't found an answer for my question.

Comment: Are you sure the root layout (e.g., linear, relative, etc) is set with a ``fill_parent`` width/height and not to some fixed size?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Main layout:

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

And there is no changes to it's size.

Answer (score 1):

Have you go through this lines in the link given by you?

res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")

res/layout-small/my_layout.xml            // layout for small screen size

res/layout-large/my_layout.xml            // layout for large screen size

res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml        **// layout for extra large screen size** i

res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml   // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density

res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density

res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density

for different size devices, make different folder as given above like layout-small,layout-large.. and put your designing xml in that.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Found the solution by myself. The OS haven't resized application because in my case it had build target Android 1.5. The adjustment of sizes appeared in version 1.6. Found it when "played" with supports-screens in Manifest.xml.

Comment: Would I also be able to use @dimen inside each folder to associate the size with screen?